# shorter way of a regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This must matches only these numbers:  `110, 220, 330, 440, 550, 660, 770, 880, 990`  (not with 000). Is there a shorter way to this regex (pcre)?

```
/^(1{2}|2{2}|3{2}|4{2}|5{2}|6{2}|7{2}|8{2}|9{2})0$/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
/\b([1-9])\g{1}0\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE5fF6/1)

Breakup of regex:

```
\b      # word boundary
[1-9]   # match digit 1-9 and group them as captured group #1
\g{1}   # back-reference to group #1
0       # match 0
\b      # word boundary
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't match 110 2. You know what I think about code only answers

Comment: see the linked demo in answer.

Comment: @GavinJackson wow, no! Please look at the first revision of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30592502/1

Comment: @Rizier123, ah understood, please excuse me

Comment: if we want to increase the count of starter number like `333330` we could multiply the back-reference, I gess.. `/^([1-9])\g{1}{4}0$/`

Comment: @Rizier123: you have forgotten the "g" in your regex101 test: `\{1}` => `\g{1}`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I just think you have to read about what you are writing, otherwise you can't say something about that, which you didn't read. And I'm think I'm pretty correct with my comments, since the first revision doesn't have the g in it.

Comment: @CevdetHamarat: If this answer worked for you then you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I get accused two times out of a mistake not on my side and then my comment got removed.. (My comments are always intended to be constructive, informative and help to clear things)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter regexp that should work:

```
/^([1-9])\1[0]$/
```

It uses a back reference to the first matched character to match the second. This ensures the `11`, `22`, `33`, etc. pattern.

Here is an explanation of the characters used in the expression from regex101:

> - `^` assert position at start of a line
> - 1st Capturing group `([1-9])`
>
>   - `[1-9]` match a single character in the range between 1 and 9
> - `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
> - `[0]` matches the character 0 literally
> - `$` assert position at end of a line

You can test it here:
https://regex101.com/r/oV6rE7/1

Comment: The second capture group is useless, remove it.

Comment: Sure. Removed now. I guess it improved performance slightly although it makes the solution a one character longer as you need to avoid the following `0` and it doesn't improve the readability imo.

Comment: You are right, I haven't seen the ambiguity due to the following `0`. Several workarounds without a capture group: https://regex101.com/r/hH5cZ5/1 (version 1,2,3)

Comment: Awesome! I think v1 makes the most sense. Updated to use that instead. Thanks.